# GROUP BY and Aggregation over between a datetime range

Tags: sql-server

I have a flat data and I am trying to aggregate all the data between 60 seconds (meaning the data between plus or minus 60 seconds should be aggregated as single row/record where Fname and Lname match:

Here is the row data:

```
RefNumber       Calenderdate            Fname   Lname   Rate
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:04.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.05
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:04.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.04
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:04.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.32
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:21.000  JAMES   BRAD    2.19
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:23.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.34
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:23.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.2
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:23.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.3
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:23.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.36
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:23.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.38
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:23.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.53
REF-55250      2019-05-13 12:57:25.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.02
REF-55250      2019-05-13 14:09:34.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.51
REF-55250      2019-05-13 15:45:53.000  JAMES   BRAD    0.51
```

Here is the desired output

```
RefNumber       Fname   Lname   Rate    
REF-55250       JAMES   BRAD    2.19
REF-55250       JAMES   BRAD    0.51
REF-55250       JAMES   BRAD    0.51
```

Comment: sorry, it's my first time using the site. the row data and desired output get messed up. i post it as table data, but it doesn't show as such

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service website.  Post your attempt.  If it doesn't work, we will try to help you.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried aggregate functions and sub queries in different ways, and none yield the right answer. Please help. I am new to SQL

Comment: @SQLcoder Still don't see the code.  If your query yield the right answer, what's the point of asking this question???

Comment: Eric, i said none of what i have tried get me the right answer. that's why i am looking for help, please.

Comment: Do you just want the MAX rate for every minute? The example seems to show the max value, but your problem statement is unclear as to which aggregate you really want or need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess

The `convert(varchar(16),[Calenderdate],121)` will truncate your datetime to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

```
Select RefNumber
      ,FName
      ,LName
      ,Rate = sum(Rate) 
 From  YourTable
 Group By RefNumber
         ,FName
         ,LName
         ,convert(varchar(16),[Calenderdate],121)
```

**Returns**

```
RefNumber   FName   LName   Rate
REF-55250   JAMES   BRAD    4.73
REF-55250   JAMES   BRAD    0.51
REF-55250   JAMES   BRAD    0.51
```

Comment: It should look like this.
RefNumber   FName   LName     Rate
REF-55250   JAMES    BRAD        4.73
REF-55250   JAMES    BRAD        0.51
REF-55250   JAMES    BRAD        0.51

Comment: @SQLcoder That is not what was posted as your desired output.  Is is a small matter to change max()  to sum()  see updated answer